# asp:GridView HYPERLINKFIELD - asp code inside datanavigateurlformatstring

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a page to search products by their name.
In many pages I work with product codes. If the user does not know the product code, I let him go to this page, search by name, and then select one of the results and get back to the page he came from.

In the results of the search by name I set an HyperLinkField that will redirect to a certain page , with a paramter of the product code.

My code is like this:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" Runat="server" 
  DataSource='<%# GetData(pName.Text) %>' AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name">
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" 
              VerticalAlign="Middle"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField  DataField="Code"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:ImageField ControlStyle-Width="150px"  ControlStyle-Height="150px" DataImageUrlField="PictureURL" ></asp:ImageField>
        <ASP:HYPERLINKFIELD text=">>" datanavigateurlfields="Code"  datanavigateurlformatstring="priceUpdater.aspx?ProductCode={0}"></ASP:HYPERLINKFIELD> 
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Where GetData is a function that returns an object of type Product with the fields, name,Code,image etc.

As you can see, this link in the HYPERLINKFIELD will redirect to a page called priceUpdater with the parameter of the product code.

I want this page to be dynamic. 
I have tried to add a paramter to the search page like this

```
 <%string pageRequested = Page.Request.QueryString["SearchScreen"];%>
```

and now im trying to use the HYPERLINK like this:

```
<ASP:HYPERLINKFIELD text=">>" datanavigateurlfields="Code"  datanavigateurlformatstring="<%=pageRequested%>.aspx?ProductCode={0}"></ASP:HYPERLINKFIELD>
```

But the page that the link reffers to is just as plain text as wrriten (http://mysite.com/%3C%=pageRequested%>.aspx?ProductCode=2450)

How can I make this work?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried creating and setting the URL from code-behind in the OnItemDataBound event? I find this is the best approach when the binding has more complex logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with that:

```
<asp:TemplateField>                     
<ItemTemplate>
    <ASP:HYPERLINK text=">>" NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("~/{0}.aspx?ProductCode={1}",Page.Request.QueryString["SearchScreen"],Eval("Code")) %>'></ASP:HYPERLINK> 
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: nope... I get this error: "Databinding expressions are only supported on objects that have a DataBinding event. 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLinkField' does not have a DataBinding event"

Comment: @Programer can you try with <asp:Hyperlink> instead of<asp:HyperlinkField> and wrap it inside <asp:TemplateField><ItemTemplate>

Comment: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlField' must contain items of the type System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCollection  . 'ASP:HYPERLINK' is type of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink'.

Comment: @Programer have you wrapped it inside <asp:TemplateField><ItemTemplate><asp:HyperLink></asp:HyperLink></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateFiled>  ?? If so I don't have other ideas :/

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `HyperLinkField` you need to extend datasource object returned by `GetData` method with value that comes with `pageRequested` query string parameter.

In that case markup for HyperLinkField will be following:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField text=">>" 
    datanavigateurlfields="PageRequested,Code"
    datanavigateurlformatstring="{0}.aspx?ProductCode={1}"></asp:HyperLinkField>
```

But this will work only if you add `PageRequested` as a public field or property to an object that is returned by `GetData` method.

If this is not an option than you need to implement your own `"LinkField"` control inherited from `DataControlField` or use `ItemTemplate` as it was suggested by [Nitin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17804677/1314859).

Comment: This worked right out of the box for a GridHyperLinkColumn in a RadGrid. +1 for making it so clean.

Answer (score 1):

Replace HYPERLINKFIELD  with TemplateField containing HyperLink and bind it in grid's rowdatabound event

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSource='<%# GetData(pName.Text) %>'
OnRowDataBound="Grd_RowDatabound"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name">
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Code"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:ImageField ControlStyle-Width="150px" ControlStyle-Height="150px" DataImageUrlField="PictureURL">
        </asp:ImageField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkNavigate" runat="server" NavigateUrl="" Text=">>"></asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**CODEBEHIND**

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    public List<myData> GetData(string param)
    {
        List<myData> lst = new List<myData>();
        lst.Add(new myData() { Name = "Hello", Code = "World", PictureURL = "Images/Select.png" });
        return lst;
    }

    public string pageRequested
    {
        get {
            return Page.Request.QueryString["SearchScreen"];
        }
    }

    protected void Grd_RowDatabound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            HyperLink lnkNavigate = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("lnkNavigate");
            if (lnkNavigate != null)
            {
                myData obj = (myData)e.Row.DataItem;
                lnkNavigate.NavigateUrl = pageRequested + ".aspx?ProductCode="+obj.Code;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class myData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string PictureURL { get; set; }
}
```